# Should CodeLite workspaces be shared?

Tags: git, project, share, collaboration, codelite

I'm working on a project where several people is working on the same code via Git.

I'm just wondering if everyone working on this project should share the same workspace (via the `./foo.workspace` file), or just share the project (via the `./foo/foo.project` file).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can **definitely** share a codelite workspace (and you are **encouraged to do so**).

Nothing in the workspace is kept in absolute paths by design (all file paths, project paths, build order etc are kept in relative paths)

Since codelite is a cross platform IDE, keeping the workspace movable - not only between different developers, but also between different OSs - has a big part of the current workspace/project design.

Also note that the although most of the important information is kept on the project level, the workspace is the one that keeps the following:

- The build matrix (which you can configure from the build->configuration manager menu), see this for more information: [Configuration Manager](http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/ConfigurationManager)
- The active project

Here is a list of files/directories that you should avoid adding to your git repo:

- Anything under your WORKSPACE_PATH/.codelite directory - this folder is intended to be used per-user
- Any generated Makefile (either Makefile or .mk)
- Any generated .txt files (these are used during the link stage, and will typically be named .txt

HTH,

Eran, Author of CodeLite IDE

Comment: Probably should be another question but.... in file `../.codelite/*.workspace.user` there are some options that I would like to make global (like project indentation options to keep them consistent between users). Is there a way to do this? - e.g. is there a *.workspace.shared file concept or some such?