# .gitignore file for CodeLite IDE 15.0.0 workspace

Tags: git, codelite

Is there a model `.gitignore` file for a CodeLite IDE 15.0.0 workspace?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26196519/3428092) provides some suggestions for files that should not be added to source control, however it's from 2014 so I'm not sure it's current for 15.0.0. For example, I see a `tags` file in the workspace root that looks like it probably shouldn't be under source control.

Below is what I'm currently working with.

```
.codelite
Makefile
*.txt
Debug
*.mk
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to get some idea is GitHub or any other source code hosting services.

A quick [GitHub search](https://github.com/search?q=gitignore%2C+codelite&type=code) says that below is the common pattern followed most people:

```
*.mk
*.project
*.workspace
compile_commands.json
Makefile
# generated directories
.codelite/

*.session
*.tags
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending [`@Asif Kamran Malick`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2915738/asif-kamran-malick)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66922922/13514657) a bit is this:

```
# CodeLite IDE
*.mk
*.txt
*.project
*.workspace
compile_commands.json
Makefile
.codelite/
*.session
*.tags
tags

# Builds
Debug/
```

I also excluded build files and the `tags` file.